# MongoDB (Mongoose) Search Query with including text?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If datas are

```
[ 
   { title: "banana awesome" },
   { title: "banana is good" },
   { title: "banana is good hahaha" },
   { title: "banana is delicious" },
]
```

And I want to query "banana good"

The result should be:

```
 [
   { title: "banana is good" },
   { title: "banana is good hahaha" }
 ]
```

What I tried

```
const searchText = "banana good"

Fruits.find({ title: { $regex: `.*${searchText}.*`} }
Fruits.find({ title: { $regex: searchText }}
```

Both are not working. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your regex is not correct. I am not a regex expert either. But, this should work.

```
Fruits.find({ title: /banana.+good/i });
```

You have to build a regex string like `/banana.+good/i` this from your given string.

You are searching for exactly a substring `banana good`. But, there is no such substring in the database.

Comment: How do I use `variable`

Comment: You can use `str.replace()` function to replace every `space` by `.+`. Example: `searchText.replace(' ', '.+')`.

Comment: const re = new RegExp(`${productName.replace(/ /g, '.+')}`, 'gi')
        const cosmetics = await Cosmetics.find({ productName: re}, null, { limit: 10 })

Comment: Now I can do it!

Comment: @Juntae Be careful about the `g` you are using. It means regex will continue to search the string even if it already finds it. For example: `banana good banana good` for this string if you use g then it will look for the full string but if you don't use g then it will stop searching after finding the first `banana good`. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without adding a regex to your Query

```
const searchText = "banana good"

Fruits.find({ title: /.*${searchText}.*/ }
```